# Logic Apps - Quotes added to HTTP request

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am using a string variable to populate the body of an HTTP request.  The API call is made but there are quote enclosing the string value.

HTTP settings
[image: HTTP Settings]

Run history

[image: Run history]

Receiving API

[image: Received by API]

From the last screenshot you can see that there are enclosing quotes on the receiving API.

How do I remove these?

Thanks

Comment: The issue is not with Logic apps design, its with postman mock server, In postman you will get quotations in that way only

Comment: @RithwikBojja, thanks for taking the time to answer.  I didn't realise this, and it helped me find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I remove these?

AFAIK, this is not possible, as it is not the issue with logic app, as logic app is sending body this way:

[image]

Postman mock server api is taking string or plain text with quotations as below:

[image]

The request body has quotations  even for content-type : text/csv also.

To test when I send json as input :

[image]

I got something like this:

[image]

So AFAIK, the quotations cannot be removed as you sending text.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input on Postman adding the quotes, I called the mock API from Postman and it also added quotes.

I figured out the that quotes were a red herring, the destination API I was calling was failing for a different reason.

All good now, thanks for your support.